# Making a request with Axios inside Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a script that updates the content of an API. There are several, so the only way is to call repeatedly to the endpoint to get the content of each API. When I am already inside the promise all, and I have the array of promises, what I do is iterating and updating the content that I have obtained.

Although the code seems to be working with an API only, I don't know what is the ideal way to make requests with Axios or fetch inside a promise.all or if just making the request is enough. Think that if for example there are 500 sequences, it will iterate through them and update their content.

The code is:

```
let promises = [];
data.sequences.forEach((sequence) => {
    promises.push(axios.get(
        `https://${conf.server.hostname}:${conf.server.port}/resource/${conf.version}/${sequence}`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer bbbbbbb'
            }
        }
    ))
});

Promise.all(promises).
then((sequences) => {
     //for each sequence to update
    for (let i = 0; i < sequences.length; i++) {
        let indexPromise = sequences[i];
        axios.put(
            `https://${conf.server.hostname}:${conf.server.port}/resource/${conf.version}/${sequenceName}`,
            indexPromise.data, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            logger.debug(`Updating content : ${sequenceName}`);
        }).catch((err) => {
            logger.error(`Error updating content`, err);
        })

    }
    return callback(null, data)

}).catch((err) => {
    logger.error(`Error getting content:`, err);
});
```

Comment: from where you get sequences?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?  You aren't waiting for the second loop of `axios` calls to finish.  You also need to collect them and `Promise.all()` them if you don't want to call the callback until everything is done.  And, by the way, it's an anti-pattern to wrap a callback around a bunch of promises.  Just return a promise from this function that represents when everything is done.  One of the reasons it's an anti-pattern is that you will notice that when you get an error, you never call your callback.

Comment: so should I do the same as I did with the get call?

Comment: Basically, the same thing, yes.  Personally, I wouldn't structure the code this way.  I'd `.get()` one, then `.put()` it as one linked operation and then `Promise.all` one set of complete operations, rather than collecting all the gets before doing any puts.

Comment: how would you structure it? I have doubts how to link operations in axios.

Comment: Yes, you can do the same as you did in `get` method. for more detail 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this structure that makes the `.get()` and `.put()` into a combined operation and then runs `Promise.all()` once on the combined operations:

```
function someFunction() {

    const corePath = `https://${conf.server.hostname}:${conf.server.port}/resource/${conf.version}`;

    // return a promise that indicates when we're all done or had an error
    return Promise.all(data.sequences.map(sequence => {
        return axios.get(`${corePath}/${sequence}`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer bbbbbbb'
            }
        }).then(data => {
            return axios.put(`${corePath}/${sequenceName}`, data, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        }).then(() => {
            logger.debug(`Updating content : ${sequenceName}`);
        }).catch(err => {
            logger.error(`Error updating content`, err);
            throw err;
        });
    });
}
```

Other notes:

1. Don't mix plain callbacks and promises.  If you need to communicate back to some other code when this is done or has an error, then return your promise - don't use a callback.
2. You don't show where `sequenceName` comes from.  Your debug output makes it seem like it's something that varies by request, but it isn't defined anywhere in the code in your question.
3. If you want the promise this is returning resolve with some data, then return that value from the final `.then()`.  Your question shows you calling a callback and passing it `data`, but doesn't show where that comes from.

Comment: yes, I have omitted several things, those values in your example would be obtained in the data. I have 5 functions that are passing data to the next sequentially through an async.waterfall, so the callback. I have modified your example and if it works because it is the last call, but I would like to refactor it. How could I pass data from one function to another without the waterfall and using only promises?

Comment: nevermind jfriend00, I restructured all the code without callbacks and only promises. Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I explained myself wrong. I have followed your solution also in other functions I had, so thank you very much for the advice. I just accepted your answer.

Comment: @Rusty23 - No problem.  I guess I misinterpreted your comment.